# How to stop textchangedlistener being executed infinitely after changing text once?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, textchanged

I have been working on a stock keeping application as a demo to learn kotlin and android studio, I have added textchangedlistener in a recycler view item, which everytime it text is changed, gets information from Api and displays new item on textview. This works good for only one time, After that it keeps infinitely changing. please check video for better understanding : [ScreenRecording](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t_2Gm60q3rero6p9pEUXe-aNGYP192ug/view?usp=sharing) .

Here is my rcv adapter :

```
class RecyclerViewAdapterU (val dataList:ArrayList<ModelClass>): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapterU.ViewHolder>() {
var _binding: UploadItemViewBinding? = null
val binding get() = _binding!!
override fun onCreateViewHolder(
    parent: ViewGroup,
    viewType: Int
): RecyclerViewAdapterU.ViewHolder {

    val v =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.upload_item_view, parent, false)
    _binding = UploadItemViewBinding.bind(v)
    return ViewHolder(binding.root)
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") position: Int) {


    bindItems(dataList[position])
    holder.getStock()
    holder.updateStockDetail()
}
fun bindItems(data: ModelClass) {

    binding.apply {
        itemquant.text=data.item_quant
        uploadItemName.text = data.item_name
        uploadMfg.text = data.mfg
        skuStock.setText(data.item_stock.toString())
        skuCode.setText(data.sku_code)
    }

}

fun getUpdatedDetails(skucode:String,pos:Int){
    val call: Call<List<ModelClass>>? =
        ApiClient.instance?.myApi?.getfromsku(skucode)!!
    call!!.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ModelClass>?> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<ModelClass>?>,
            response: Response<List<ModelClass>?>
        ) {
            val skuDetails=response.body()

            if (skuDetails != null) {
                dataList.removeAt(pos)
                for (i in skuDetails){
                    println(i.item_name)
                    dataList.add(pos,i)
                }
                notifyItemChanged(pos)
            }

        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ModelClass>?>, t: Throwable) {
        }
    })
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return dataList.size
}


inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


    fun getStock() {

        binding.skuStock.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                for (i in 0 until RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected.size){
                    if (editable.toString().trim()!=""){
                        var x= editable.toString().trim().toInt()
                        RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected[adapterPosition].item_stock=x
                        //getting current itemstock before pushing update.
                        //assigning latest itemstock to the data for the update
                    }
                }
            }

        })
    }

    fun updateStockDetail(){
        binding.skuCode.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
            override fun beforeTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(charSequence: CharSequence, i: Int, i1: Int, i2: Int) {

            }
            override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                var x:String=""
                var pos:Int=adapterPosition
                    for (i in 0 until RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected.size){

                        if (editable.toString().trim()!=""){
                            x=editable.toString().trim()
                            //RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected[adapterPosition].sku_code=x
                            println("$x in if")
                        }
                    }
                    //println(RecyclerViewAdapter.ob.dataSelected[adapterPosition].sku_code)
                    //getting edited text and calling the function to get updated details.
                    getUpdatedDetails(x,pos)
    binding.skuStock.removeTextChangedListener(this)

                }
        })
    }

}
```

}

If possible please review my code and let me know what are things i need to work on.
Note: `ob.dataselected` is a global variable from another recyclerview adapter.
Textchangedlistener i am talking about is in the `fun updateStockDetail()`

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for [afterTextChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) we see the following:

> This method is called to notify you that, somewhere within s, the text has been changed. It is legitimate to make further changes to s from this callback, **but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively.**

(The emphasis is mine.) I don't see where you remove the text watcher before changing the text, so you may be in an infinite loop.

To remove the text watcher use [removeTextChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#removeTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)). You can replace the text watcher after making changes.

Comment: Hey @Cheticamp , I added removetextchangedlistener, but it doesnt make difference, Problem is not happening when i change the text for firs time. Actually problem appears after one data change in textview. I can change nay number of data in edittext, but when that edittext data reflects textviews, then it causes infinite loop.

Comment: @SyedAhad Check to make sure that multiple text watchers are not active at the same time. The text watcher must be removed before changing the text in `afterTextChanged()` and added back in after changing the text.

Comment: Hey, I analyzed my whole code , and i found notifyitemchanged is causeing the infinite loop. Is there anyway to solve it?

Comment: @SyedAhad `notifyitemchanged()` will force the view holder to be rebound. I would say that you don't want to apply the change listener until after binding.

Comment: I cant find a way to move the notifyitemchanged anywhere else. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: @SyedAhad I haven't gone line-by-line through your code, but you might want to consider removing any text watcher at the beginning of `onBindViewHolder()` (if one is attached) and reapplying it at the very end of `onBindViewHolder()`. Anyway, I assume that you only want to watch the text when the user can make changes and not when your program does. So, make sure that the text watcher isn't applied when your program is making changes.

Comment: I tried that, its still same.